# IP Hook through Java

Tags: java, network-programming

I'm trying to figure out the basic idea about IP Hooking. I'm trying to make a program similar to what the hosts file does in windows but for one specific program. How would I go about doing this?

I want to implement it on a website.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but perhaps you could, create a HashMap of String to InetAddresses to associate the name of a IP/Hostname in a list or even an array of InetAddresses then create a new socket() using that IP/Hostname and call public void shutdownInput(). Like I said I never tested it but it may be worth a shot.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#shutdownInput()

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html